# CreateWindow() style parameter being ignored?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

In my Windows application, I'm creating a new window using the CreateWindow() function. The registration and window creation are as follows:

```
// Set up the capture window
WNDCLASS wc = {0};

// Set which method handles messages passed to the window
wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowMessageRedirect<CStillCamera>;
// Make the instance of the window associated with the main application
wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
// Set the cursor as the default arrow cursor
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
// Set the class name required for registering the window and identifying it for future
// CreateWindow() calls
wc.lpszClassName = c_wzCaptureClassName.c_str();

RegisterClass(&wc); /* Call succeeding */

HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
    c_wzCaptureClassName.c_str() /* lpClassName */,
    c_wzCaptureWindowName.c_str() /* lpWindowName */,
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_MAXIMIZE /* dwStyle */,
    CW_USEDEFAULT /* x */,
    CW_USEDEFAULT /* y */,
    CW_USEDEFAULT /*nWidth */,
    CW_USEDEFAULT /* nHeight */,
    NULL /* hWndParent */,
    NULL /* hMenu */,
    GetModuleHandle(NULL) /* hInstance */,
    this /* lpParam */
);


if (!hWnd)
{
    return false;
}

ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);
```

I go on to use the window and update it with streaming video, which works correctly. However, it seems that whatever I pass as the dwStyle parameter of CreateWindow() gets ignored. The window has no title bar, minimize, or maximize buttons as one would expect from an overlapped window. Also, the window isn't maximized. Strangely enough, changing dwStyle to

```
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_HSCROLL /* dwStyle */
```

now shows the double-sided left/right arrow when hovering over the window but with no actual scroll bars. Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this strange behavior?

Comment: Why `= {0}` instead of just `= {}` ? Did you ever call RegisterClass? Are you passing through messages to DefWindowProc? (That's what draws the title bar and such)

Comment: Sorry - I accidentally edited out the line about RegisterClass(). I am indeedy calling RegisterClass and all messages are being passed to DefWindowProc() as well.

Comment: Actually, I lied! The problem was that DefWindowProc() wasn't being called in WndProc(). If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing of the title bar and other such things requires that you pass unhandled window messages to `DefWindowProc`. For example, the title bar is painted during the `WM_NCPAINT` message. If you don't pass the message to `DefWindowProc` that just doesn't get done.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment in the [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The WS_MINIMIZE and WS_MAXIMIZE styles may be ignored depending on the values
>   specified in STARTUPINFO.dwFlags and STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow when the process was created.

The minimize and maximize boxes must be explicitly enabled with WS_MINIMIZEBOX and WS_MAXIMIZEBOX. You probably want WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW instead of just WS_OVERLAPPED; that will include the minimize and maximize boxes.

Comment: `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` is `(WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX)` -- it's already explicitly specified. (Moreover, he's talking about `WS_MAXIMIZE`, not `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX`)

Comment: @Billy, for some reason I read WS_OVERLAPPED and not WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW - my bad. But the part about WS_MAXIMIZE is relevant: "Also, the window isn't maximized." I'm glad you figured it out, I may delete this answer after a while.